# Boolean Network Simplification using Satisfiability Don't care Conditions

Tags: synthesis, optimization

I couldn't really understand how SDC conditions are applied to minimize the following Boolean Network from [Giovanni De Micheli's slide](http://icwww.epfl.ch/~ghasemza/DTIS/Slides_presentations/DT12.pdf) I am studying.

Given:

$$x=a'+b$$
$$y=abx + a'cx$$

Minimize \$fy\$ to obtain \$gy = ax + a'c\$

Comment: Where do you get stuck? What does it look like when you substitute the equation for `x` into the equation for `y`?

Comment: SDCx = ab'x + a'x' +bx', the book says this is used to simplify fy in to gy, I couldn't see that. and If I substitute the equation for x into y, I will remove x which is still in gy.

Answer (score 1):

$$ y=abx+a'cx $$
replacing \$x=a′+b\$ & reducing further:
$$ y = ab +a'c + a'cb $$
Using rule:  \$A+A'B = A+B\$
$$y= ab +a'c $$
$$y=  aa' + ab +a'c $$
$$y=  ax +a'c $$

You can get the same with K-map also.

Comment: how about using the condition of SDC? SDCx = x'(a'+b) + x(a'+b)' = ab'x + a'x' + bx'.